# MongoDB : I have a debit/credit collection and need balance of each user

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of transactions : sender_id, receiver_id, amount.

```
{
   "_id": {
       "$oid": "55279f6c1a7f98030043ddf3"
   },
   "sender_id": "00001",
   "receiver_id": "00002",
   "amount": 10000,
   "__v": 0
}
```

For a given user, I can get the sum where he is receiver : his credits

```
Transaction.aggregate( 
  { $match : {sender_id : user.id}     },     
  { $group : { _id : "$sender_id", total : { $sum : "$amount" } }  },
  function(err, result){
     ....
  }
);
```

Replacing "receiver" with "sender" and I get his debits :

```
Transaction.aggregate( 
  { $match : {receiver_id : user.id}     },     
  { $group : { _id : "$receiver_id", total : { $sum : "$amount" } }  },
  function(err, result){
     ....
  }
);
```

So I can process ( credits **-** debits ) and have his balance

```
Transaction.aggregate( 
  { $match : {receiver_id : user.id}     },     
  { $group : { _id : "$receiver_id", total : { $sum : "$amount" } }  },
  function(err, received){

    Transaction.aggregate( 
      { $match : {sender_id : user.id}     },     
      { $group : { _id : "$sender_id", total : { $sum : "$amount" } }  },
      function(err, sent){

         received[0] - sent[0]   // Balance

      }
    );

  }
);
```

I would like to :

- Improve and have the balance in 1 request
- Get a list of my users and their balance

I have relational databases experience and maybe I think to much this way, not enough Mongo way.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a sample document? It's hard to determine how the debits or credits are stored as you have explained above.

Comment: Sure :)  I added it in the same code sample

Comment: So there are different collections, each for debits and credits?

Comment: @JulienD how you calculated `credits_sum` and `debits_sum` ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I rewrote my message to answer your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following aggregation:

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "sender_id" : user.id }, { "receiver_id" : user.id }] } },
    { "$project" : { 
        "user" : { "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$sender_id", user_id] }, "$sender_id", "$receiver_id" ] },
        "amount" : { "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$sender_id", user_id] }, { "$multiply" : [-1, "$amount"] }, "$amount" ] }
    } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$user", "balance" : { "$sum" : "$amount" } } }
])
```

This aggregation gives wrong results if, for some reason, a user is both the sender and receiver on a single transaction, but it can be modified to handle that case as well. It's worth doing that to make sure you understand what's going on.